# How to apply function to value in nested array recursively using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested

I have an array of objects that have attributes like `name` as well as `children`, which holds a nested array of same such objects.

I have a custom function `newString` that I would like to apply to the attribute `name` and update it on each object and its nested children.

I wrote a recursive function. I can see the new names if I `console.log` them inside the function, the change in `name` is not reflected in the resulting object.

```
const myObj = [
  { name: "2021",
    score: null,
    goal: 2,
    children: [
    { name: "2002",
      score: null,
      goal: 3,
      children: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    },
    { name: "2005",
      score: null,
      goal: 7,
      children: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    }],
  }
];

function parse(arr: any) {
    return arr.map((obj: any) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          parse(obj[key]);
        }

        if (key === "name") {
          newString(obj[key]);
          console.log(newString(obj[key]));
        }
      });

      return obj;
    });
  }
```

The goal would be to have the `newString` function applied to every value under the key `name` in the array and all the children.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you actually ran those parameters? `arr: any` and `obj: any`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that when you call `newString(obj[key])`, you are passing the result of the expression `obj[key]` to the function `newString`, which is a string value. You are NOT passing a reference to the key attribute of `obj`, and any update you do on it inside the function `newString` will not be reflected on `obj[key]`.

For more information, search for [pass by value vs by reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript/).

Now, said that, let me tell you that you are in the right path with a recursive function. You could actually make use of some nice javascript syntax to write a very simple and straightforward implementation of it:

```
parse = (f,a) => a.map(
  ({name:n, children:c, ...o}) => ({...o, name:f(n), children:parse(f,c)}))
```

That you can call just like this:

```
parse(newString, myObj)
```

```js
const myObj = [
  { name: "2100", score: null, goal: 2,
    children: [
    { name: "2110", score: null, goal: 3, 
      children: [
      { name:"2111", score:null, goal:13, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2112", score:null, goal:23, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2113", score:null, goal:33, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2114", score:null, goal:43, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2115", score:null, goal:53, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2116", score:null, goal:63, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2117", score:null, goal:73, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2118", score:null, goal:83, children:[] } 
    ]},
    { name: "2120", score: null, goal: 7,
      children: [
      { name:"2121", score:null, goal:15, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2122", score:null, goal:25, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2123", score:null, goal:35, children:[] }, 
      { name:"2124", score:null, goal:45, children:[] } 
    ]}
  ]},
  { name: "2200", score: null, goal: 2, children: [] }
]

const parse = (f,a) => a.map(
  ({name:n, children:c, ...o}) => ({...o, name: f(n), children: parse(f, c)}))

const newString = s => `new ${s}`
console.log(parse(newString, myObj))
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: Cool. If the answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted and vote up